# Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Tags: xamarin.ios

Currently I'm working on a xamarin.ios project. when I run my app, the output window says,

```
2017-04-17 19:10:33.666 sample.iOS[2982:389704] Xamarin.iOS: Debugger loaded with custom transport (fd: 4)
2017-04-17 19:10:33.667 sample.iOS[2982:389716] Xamarin.iOS: Established connection with the IDE (fd: 6)
2017-04-17 19:10:33.667 sample.iOS[2982:389716] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'
2017-04-17 19:10:33.699 sample.iOS[2982:389704] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)
2017-04-17 19:10:33.803 sample.iOS[2982:389704] Xamarin.iOS: Added dllmap for objc_msgSend
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: any update with profiler ?

Comment: @Navaneethan any update after 6 years?

Answer (score 1):

try to right click on IOS Projekt go to IOS Debug and the enable Profile.

I found this solution but there is nothing on my side maybe it helps you.

If you found an other solution pls write here.